# Error: The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the class 'QuerySnapshot'

Tags: firebase, flutter

I followed the same code as instructed by my instructor but I think due to update i'm getting this error:

[image: Error documents]

what to use instead of this code?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for next time. The problem is that `documents` property is deprecated so use `docs` now. Check the duplicate also

Comment: Watch the following link for the changes.(https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/)